# How to create permalink in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, permalinks

I want to redirect a link to another with .htaccess file in Linux host. Can you help me?

```
from: http://example.com/examp
to: http://example.com/examp.php
```

And another one for my other site

```
from: http://example.com/examp
to: http://example.com/user.php?u=examp
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need **mod_rewrite** enabled for this. Start with placing these lines into .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

---

TBH I'm not 100% sure what do you mean exactly by permalink and how do you want to redirect, so I will provide 2 variants for each URL: rewrite (internal redirect) and redirect (301 Permanent Redirect).

1. This will rewrite (internal redirect) request for `http://example.com/examp` to `http://example.com/examp.php` while URL will remain unchanged in browser:

```
RewriteRule ^examp$ examp.php [L]
```

2. This will do the same as above but with proper redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) when URL will change in browser:

```
RewriteRule ^examp$ http://example.com/examp.php [R=301,L]
```

3. This will rewrite (internal redirect) request for `http://example.com/examp` to `http://example.com/user.php?u=examp` while URL will remain unchanged in browser:

```
RewriteRule ^examp$ user.php?u=examp [QSA,L]
```

4. This will do the same as above but with proper redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) when URL will change in browser:

```
RewriteRule ^examp$ http://example.com/user.php?u=examp [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Useful link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

You will need mod_rewrite enabled for this

from: http://example.com/123
to: http://example.com/index.php?q=123

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at RewriteRules and know/understand regular expressions. It'll be something like this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/examp$ /examp.php [R=301,L]
    - and - 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]+$ /user.php?u=$1 [R=301,L]
```

The latter example will take what's in-between the [] and place it in the $1 variable

Here is a good link to get you started:
http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml