# Permalinks with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, permalinks

I am currently working on a website I am making from SCRATCH :) Anyhow users will be able to create accounts (login and register pages already done), and then they will be able to view there profile. Now the problem I am running into is each user needs there own permalink for there profile's URL. I do not know how to go about doing this though! :( All I can find is using Wordpress to do it for me, but I do not want that. I would like to go about doing this with only PHP and HTML/CSS. Please help me out, thank you! :)

**UPDATE 1**

Thank you for the relpys, I am still a little confused though. Now if I use a GET, will that actually save the file? How exactly do permalinks work (sorry very confused! :O )? Like when I create the permalink is that creating a new file as well with the code inside of it? If so what would I be writing for that?

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry I am specifying what I am really asking. When a user created a account, I want it to AUTO create them a permalink (which would be a new file right?), how would I go about doing that?

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, so I am basically thinking of the same thing. So when a user creates a account this is the code that is executed:

```
//Create Account Page

$inputquery = "INSERT INTO users username VALUES :username";
                        $datasend = $connection->prepare($inputquery);
                        $datasend->execute(array(':username'=>utf8_decode($username),)); //Inputs it into the database

$username = $_POST["username"]; //The username input, then lets say that the account was created with that

$userprofile = fopen($username . ".php", "w"); //Makes a file with the users info, a PHP function

$text =  include ('base.php'); //Grabbing the base layout

fwrite($userprofile, $text); //Setting the base layout to the userprofile page
```

So once that is one the code will be in the file. Then when the page is loaded, that so called "base" code is still there, and then is replaced with the details of the user. That is my rough attempt at this, it should work! :) Thank You for all of your help! :D

Comment: something like: `yoursite.com/user.php?id=42`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784302/how-to-create-permalink-in-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GET request, which will be stored in the URL. You just access it with `$_GET['user']`, and the url will be in the form `my.site.on.the.net/user.php?user=3141`. This URL can be stored in bookmarks, put in a webpage, or whatever else and it will link to that user's profile.

This will not save the file by itself. You will need to store the user information somewhere outside your web root, then use the PHP file to access that info based on the ID.  You don't want to store the entire webpage; just store the information that is unique to that user (On SO, that would be stuff like their About Me, reputation, badges, etc.)

**EDIT:** Simple example (note that it doesn't have any password protection or anything else to prevent any random stranger from accessing it)

user.php:

```
<?php
    function getPoints(){
        // get the number of points from your data source
    }
    function getName(){
        // get the name from your data source
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <h1>Hello, <?php echo getName();?>!</h1>
        <p>You have <?php echo getPoints();?> points.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example, the data source only needs to store the user's name and number of points. The single PHP file fills in the rest of the page. To create a new user account, you will need to add the data for the user to your data source.

Comment: What code could I use for example that WOULD save the actual permalink to a file?

Comment: It depends on how you are going to store the data. You could use a database as well, but I've never used one myself so I can't go into much detail about it. This PHP page just needs to get the data from wherever it is stored, insert the data into the right places in the HTML code, and serve it to the user.

Comment: Hello, I have been thinking a lot about this. I wanted to thank you for all of the help so far! :) And I think I have a pretty good idea of what to do. So basically when a user created a account, it will be creating a new page with PHP's function fopen(). Now once that is done, it will write in the base code. Then whenever a user accesses the page it will replace the base code with the users information.

Comment: What do you mean by base code? You only need to store information specific to that user. The PHP page contains the stuff like headers, footers, labels, and anything else that stays the same across users.

Comment: By base code I mean the layout of my page. So it will save the file with what the page would look like. Then when the page is loaded it will replace all of the part of the page with the users information. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll add an example.

Comment: Thank you kittycat3141, I added a update above :) No need to reply any longer :D I think I have gotten it..

Comment: You don't need multiple PHP files. The file called `user.php` will serve the right page based on the GET parameter. Also, creating PHP files with user input is a **very** bad idea. If my username is `importantfolder/reallyimportantfile`, I can overwrite important files with my user profile page, causing chaos and destruction.

Comment: Wait, so the ONE file user.php will show every users information?

Comment: Yes, based on the GET parameter. So it serves all users' information, but not all at once. You will need password protection if you don't want anyone to be able to see any user.

Comment: Hmm, this actually makes sense! :) The problem with this though is that you can not directly access the users profile information with the URL.

Comment: Hello, I have been reading a LOT MORE about this. With your thing, would I need a .htaccess file aswell? Thank You! :)

Comment: No, this method is rather simple. There are ways to do it like Stack Overflow, where each question has its own page, but I don't know them and this is simpler IMHO.

Comment: Hmm ok thank you! :) One final question (sorry for all of the bothering). What if someone times in a link url.com/profiles/dwwadwa, how will it go to the link if the file is only one file

Comment: The user.php file uses the GET parameter to tell which user is being viewed.

Comment: um, yea. If I enter url.com/profiles/dwwadwa it will take me to a 404 page though sense the url does "not exist" I would have to enter url.com/profiles right? this makes no sense xD

Comment: You don't need a url.com/profiles/dwwadwa, you just need the user.php file. You might want to (if you haven't already) try the example I posted to see how it works.

Comment: Hello, sorry for how long it took me to reply. I am using a localhost and it crashed (fixed now! :) ). So anyhow I am back to working on it. You thing works good, but it would NOT work correctly if I tried to direct connect to someones profile...